# How to calculate in a pandas dataframe each day's Value at risk in rolling window manner

Tags: python, pandas, series, yahoo-finance, rolling-computation

I'm working with a problem where I'm calculating [Value at Risk(VaR)](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/v/var.asp) and [Conditional Value at Risk(CVaR)](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/conditional_value_at_risk.asp).

Initially I imported all the libraries and calculated the percent change of the close price of each stock for each day. Here is my code.

**import all libraries**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
from scipy.stats import norm, t
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics
```

**Get every day's stock data using yahoo finance and calculate the percent change of everyday.**

```
def getData(stocks, start, end):
    stockData = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stocks, start=start, end=end)
    stockData = stockData['Close']
    returns_pctchange = stockData.pct_change()
    return returns_pctchange
```

**Stock list for getting the data.**

```
stockList = ['IOC', 'RELIANCE', 'BPCL', 'HINDPETRO', 'EXIDEIND']
stocks = [stock+'.NS' for stock in stockList]
endDate = dt.datetime.now()
startDate = endDate - dt.timedelta(days=800)
```

**getting the data.**

```
returns = getData(stocks, start=startDate, end=endDate)
returns = returns.dropna()
```

**Initialize the equal weights for constructing the portfolio**

```
weights = np.array([1/len(stocks) for n in stocks])
returns['portfolio'] = returns.dot(weights)
retruns
```

**Outcome**

```
Symbols     IOC.NS   RELIANCE.NS    BPCL.NS   HINDPETRO.NS  EXIDEIND.NS  portfolio
Date                        
2020-06-09  -0.026316   -0.020612   -0.031972   -0.022176   0.000000    -0.020215
2020-06-10  -0.007722   0.022769    -0.006684   -0.017954   -0.002520   -0.002422
2020-06-11  -0.017788   -0.021913   -0.023486   -0.012509   -0.044536   -0.024046
2020-06-12  -0.000566   0.033232    0.010404    0.027284    0.021818    0.018434
2020-06-15  -0.023783   0.016207    -0.034501   -0.019682   -0.031381   -0.018628
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
2022-08-10  -0.011588   0.005979    0.008138    0.004183    -0.006013   0.000140
2022-08-11  -0.021379   0.003330    0.000152    0.000208    0.013371    -0.000863
2022-08-12  0.008457    0.016171    0.016903    0.023948    0.000314    0.013159
2022-08-16  0.022362    0.006950    0.035939    0.038845    0.031721    0.027163
2022-08-17  0.004101    0.005790    0.023417    0.030736    -0.002740   0.01226
```

**Now I'm constructing two function to calcualte Historical VaR and CVaR respectively.**

```
def historicalVaR(returns, alpha=5):
    """
    Read in a pandas dataframe of returns / a pandas series of returns.
    Output the percentile of the distribution at the given alpha confidence level.
    """
    if isinstance(returns, pd.Series):
        return np.percentile(returns, alpha)
    
    # A passed user-defined-function will be passed a Series for evaluation.
    
    elif isinstance(returns, pd.DataFrame):
        return returns.aggregate(historicalVaR, alpha=alpha)
   
    else:
        raise TypeError("Expected returns to be dataframe or series")



def historicalCVaR(returns, alpha=5):
    """
    Read in a pandas dataframe of returns / a pandas series of returns
    Output the CVaR for dataframe / series
    """
    if isinstance(returns, pd.Series):
        belowVaR = returns <= historicalVaR(returns, alpha=alpha)
        return returns[belowVaR].mean()
    
    # A passed user-defined-function will be passed a Series for evaluation.
    
    elif isinstance(returns, pd.DataFrame):
        return returns.aggregate(historicalCVaR, alpha=alpha)
   
    else:
        raise TypeError("Expected returns to be dataframe or series")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
historicalVaR(returns, alpha=5)

Symbols
IOC.NS         -0.026491
RELIANCE.NS    -0.026387
BPCL.NS        -0.028889
HINDPETRO.NS   -0.036270
EXIDEIND.NS    -0.024520
portfolio      -0.023936
dtype: float64

historicalCVaR(returns, alpha=5)
Symbols
IOC.NS         -0.039620
RELIANCE.NS    -0.038351
BPCL.NS        -0.046772
HINDPETRO.NS   -0.046224
EXIDEIND.NS    -0.034338
portfolio      -0.031564
dtype: float64
```

But this is giving me the unconditional VaR or CVaR of this 800 days but I want to create a create a rolling window to calculate the Value at Risk (VaR) over time and to calculate VaR & CVaR of each stock and the portfolio for each day with a rolling window method with lets say window size=7.

Please help me in that. Thanks!

Comment: just wondering if you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with this, my code is below. Im also just learning so any tips or comments are welcome!

```py
def compute_var(returns, alpha, window=None):
    """
    Input: pandas series of returns
    Output: percentile of return distribution at a given confidence level alpha
    """
    if isinstance(returns, pd.Series):
        if window==None:
            return np.percentile(returns, alpha)
        else:
            return returns.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x,alpha), raw=True).dropna()
            # ALT: returns.rolling(window).quantile(alpha/100)
    else:
        raise TypeError("Expected a pandas data series")

def compute_es(returns, alpha, window=None):
    """
    Input: pandas series of returns
    Output: Expected shortfall for a given confidence interval alpha
    """
    if isinstance(returns, pd.Series):
        if window==None:
            belowVaR = returns <= compute_var(returns, alpha=alpha)
            return returns[belowVaR].mean()
        else:
            return returns.rolling(window).apply(lambda x: x[x<= compute_var(x, alpha)].mean()).dropna()
    else:
        raise TypeError("Expected a pandas data series")
```